# GitlabHQ installating on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-12.04, gitlab

I am facing some problem in installing Gitlabhq on Ubuntu 12.04

I am getting this error

```
$ sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres

/usr/local/bin/bundle:9:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:9
```

Here are the different packages i have installed on my computer.

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [i686-linux]

$ gem -v
2.0.3

$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.1.0)

charlock_holmes (0.6.9.4)

io-console (0.3)

json (1.5.5)

minitest (2.5.1)

rake (0.9.2.2)

rdoc (3.9.5)

rubygems-update (2.0.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That kind of error is generally the result of using the wrong ruby version as in [issue 3706](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3706).

Using a 1.9.x ruby, as in [issue 3349](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3349#issuecomment-15962631), should solve the problem.

Comment: yes that helped ..  And i was able to install the gitlabhq 5-0 stable version. Initially i was trying to install the master version of gitlabhq which was giving me unsolved dependencies.